# Code returning "0" regardless

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box with the following values possible for selection:
"----", 
"C", 
"D", 
"E"
with the default being "----"

If the combobox choice is either "C" or "E" I need the result to be a "1"
If the combobox choice is either "----" or "D" I need the result to be a "0"

The sum of all comboboxes are then added and the result given in the tbComDataTot textbox

I am using the following code:

```
    Private Sub cbTermPurch_SelectedIndexChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbComData1.SelectedIndexChanged, cbComData2.SelectedIndexChanged, cbComData3.SelectedIndexChanged, cbComData4.SelectedIndexChanged, cbComData5.SelectedIndexChanged, cbComData6.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim cd1 As Integer = CInt(IIf(cbComData1.Text = "C" Or cbComData2.Text = "E", 1, 0))
    Dim cd2 As Integer = CInt(IIf(cbComData2.Text = "C" Or cbComData1.Text = "E", 1, 0))
    Dim cd3 As Integer = CInt(IIf(cbComData3.Text = "C" Or cbComData3.Text = "E", 1, 0))
    Dim cd4 As Integer = CInt(IIf(cbComData4.Text = "C" Or cbComData4.Text = "E", 1, 0))
    Dim cd5 As Integer = CInt(IIf(cbComData5.Text = "C" Or cbComData5.Text = "E", 1, 0))
    Dim cd6 As Integer = CInt(IIf(cbComData6.Text = "C" Or cbComData6.Text = "E", 1, 0))

    Try
        a = (cd1 + cd2 + cd3 + cd4 + cd5 + cd6)
        If a > 0 Then
            tbComDataTot.Text = a.ToString
        Else
            If a = CInt("0") Then
                tbComDataTot.Text = "0"
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'If a calculation error occurs, show Error message box
        Dim frm As New MeMsgCalcError(ex, "'Total Fuel Card Purchases' Calculation Error." & vbCrLf & "Lines 1517-1540")
        frm.Show()
    End Try
End Sub
```

### The problem is when I have a "C" or "E" selected (combobox) the code (in debug) still returns a "0" Any assistance here? Appreciate the any help offered.

responding to responses:

Corrected the error in the statement overlooking the dim statement var define.

Attempted to change to IF instead of IIF.

In debug (obviously checked debug prior to coming here for help) keeps the variable at "0" regardless of what is entered in combobox.

All edits still result in "0" being returned instead of the expected total count.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

The CB is populated by an import of a CSV file. If I manually choose the using the combobox the code works fine. I am wanting the code to read the cb after import and total with manual intervention. This similar code is used elsewhere in my program and it works fine, but is set to a strict YES/NO answer in the combobox.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried setting a break point and stepping through the code, observing the values of your variables?

Comment: What a great chance to learn about the debugger!  Set a breakpoint and see what those `cd?` expressions evaluate to for starters.

Comment: Try changing to `If` instead of using `IIf`

Comment: Even with the edit it is a simple debugging issue and VS comes with a great set of debugging tools.  Set a breakpoint and **step thru** the code one line at a time.  Use the **Locals Window** or the **mouse** to examine the values of the `cd` vars.  Are they what you expect?  Why not?

Comment: Problem resolved... rather than having SelectedIndexChange I changed to TextChanged. All is working as it is expected now. Code was correct otherwise. Thereby, the debugger would never have found the issue or hinted why it did not work since the program was operating exactly as it was coded to do so.